# Batch update array field using Ruby Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So let's say I have a model that has an array.

In some cases, I want to be able to do a batch update to add something to that array.

e.g.

`Parent is a model of {id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string, jobs :Array[string]}`

and I want to update many Parents to have one extra job.

Is there a way to do this with one command? Or do I have to go through every row in the Parent table and append?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize method

For eg: in model you can write as follows

```
serialize :<FIELD_NAME>, Array
```

And you can use group of checkboxes or radio buttons to store them.
It will store as Array.

Try it out